# How to get an Array from an EnumMap?

Tags: java, enums

In Java EnumMaps have constant access time, because they can be implemented with an array using the ordinal value of the enum as an index.

If I have an EnumMap how can I get the Array?

Example:

```
enum Abc { A, B, C };
EnumMap<Abc, String> abc = new EnumMap<Abc, String>(Abc.class);
abc.put(Abc.A, "α");
abc.put(Abc.B, "β");
abc.put(Abc.C, "γ");

String[] abcarray = ?;
```

The variable `abcarray` should contain the same as if initialized in this way:

```
String[] abcarray = new String[] { "α", "β", "γ" };
```

I can not find a method in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). Why is such a function missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can go via [the `Map.values()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) (remember that an `EnumMap` is just a specialized `Map`):

```
String[] abcarray = abc.values().toArray(new String[abc.size()]);
```

For the *reason* why no such method exists we can only speculate.

But there are two common themes in the collections framework, that come into play here:

- allow complexer operations by chaining simpler operations (which reduces the total number of operations/methods that need to be implemented, while keeping the options available)
- get rid of arrays: they have no real use once you're in "collection area"

Answer (score 2):

It is a little abstracted... try :

```
String[] abcarray = abc.values().toArray(new String[abc.size()]);
```

Comment: Will this create a new array for each call?

Comment: @ceving: if used as-is, then yes. But you can just pass in an array that you previously used and you won't re-create one each time (unless the size changes, that is).

Comment: yes, it will. You cannot (legally) access the internal array of values, and it will not have the same things you want, anyway (it will/may be larger than abc.size() and have 'null' values)